# Append and delete array of structure data into file using c

Tags: arrays, c, file, file-io, structure

I am trying to perform some operations such as add, delete, append data using an array of structures into a file in C language.
Here is my structure.

```
struct S_info
{
    char title[50];
    char sName[50];
    int rMm;
    int rDd;
    int rYy;
    int rating;
    bool deleteSong;
};
```

And I was able to add data into the file using structure. Here is the code for adding the data.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("Title: ");
    scanf("%s", &title);
    printf("\nName of the Song: ");
     .....................

    strcpy(s[i].title, title);
    strcpy(s[i].sName, sName);

    s[i].rMm = rMm;
    ...........

    fwrite(&s[i], sizeof(struct S_info), 1, outfile);
}
```

but the problem is, whenever I add new data, previous data are removed from the file. So I need to create a function that will append the new data into a file using an array of structures. Also I want to create another function that will delete.

For deleting the data I tried an approach, I created a bool variable in the structure to help me delete the data. But I don't like the code.
I searched on the Internet to append the data using structure but I did not found any good solution and the same thing happened for deleting the data.
What I need is to append and delete new data into a file using an array of structures.

Comment: When scanning for a string using the `%s` format, you should not need the address-of operator `&` for the argument. In fact, depending on the type of e.g. `title`, using `&title` can lead to possible crashes.

Comment: As for your problem, how do you open the file `outfile`? Do you open it in plain write mode which truncates (erases) the existing data in the file? Or in append mode where new data is appended to the file? Or in read-write mode?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
here is how i open the file: outfile = fopen ("songs.dat", "w");
and this is how i tried to add the data:
fwrite (&s[i], sizeof(struct S_info), 1, outfile);

Comment: @POKA open the file in append mode: fopen ("songs.dat", "a");

Comment: Please read a little about [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) and its open-mode string. With `"w"` you erase all the existing contents of the file (which is also something any decent beginners book, class or tutorial should have mentioned).

Comment: Someprogrammerdude @AnkushPandit  yes. Now it's working. Thank you so much. Appending data is working. Now I need to delete the data and update the new data into the file.

Answer (score 0):

you can  look when you open your output file, withe the 'open' function there are a lot of useful option you can use with it, (you can find it on the 'open' manual);
O_APPEND is one of theses options and it allow you to write in the file after the data that are already in it so I think it's what you want